# touch any where on screen to activate method

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have an if statement that is bringing up a SVProgressHUD that lets the user know there is an error. I would like to create a touch event programmatically but I am not sure how to define my view when I am using a tableview which was set up in interface builder

this is the code I would like to use

```
[myView addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

but I am not sure how to create myView when I am using a tableview. What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a UIButton with transparent color and add it to your view.
Then you'll be able to use the following method:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add tapGestureRecognizer to the view with target and event to handle the tap event such that when a user click or touches the view it triggers the selector.

```
UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mySelector:)]
[myView addGestureRecognizer: recognizer];
```

Then you could add the selector which simply takes the recognizer as the sender;

```
-(void)mySelector:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gr{
  // handling event  
}
```

Comment: I am having trouble with myView... how do I define that as currently I am using a tableview in Interface Builder..

Comment: If you are using interface builder then you could create outlet to connect the view in nib to the controller and then reference it from the controller or what do you mean ?